# Adding links to text from an html textarea

Tags: php, mysql, html

Is this possible? What I would like to do is designate certain text that the user writes in a text area as a link. This text is inserted into a MySQL database then pulled, and displayed elsewhere. Also the links will never really be in the same spot.

Answer (score 0):

You could could use jQuery to grab the value of the textarea on change and use ajax to send it to a php page which logs it to a mysql db, then use jQuery setInterval/ajax combo to pull back results from the php/mysql to put elsewhere on your page :)

Also you can construct the link in the php then just send back html to your page

Comment: How could I tell witch ones need links? I know I can grab the value of the text area, but no idea how I could tell witch words were designated as links. Also this is supposed to be an automated system, the user needs to be able to put in links with out knowing any code...

Comment: Well what exact input are they going to be putting in? In PHP you can make the link ie. echo "<a href='" . $theResultfromMySQL . "'>Hey i'm a link</a>";

Comment: That's close, I knew you could do something like that but what I'm trying to do is say hey this is going to be a link later on, before it goes into the database. The user would need to put in a title and link. Kind of like you do on a message board.

Comment: Well if theres any way you can get them to notify you (your code) its a link then you can do a check for that flag at the jQuery level or the PHP level...either is fine

Comment: Perhaps if I could find a way to flag it, then I could make jquery write in the html for the link in its place, and grab the next word and use it for the title of the link? I'm trying to think of a way to flag it right now..

Comment: Well unfortunately you need them to flag it, as you said they would only sometimes write a link and you wouldnt know when

Answer (score 0):

Can you describe this process a bit more?  How will the specific text within the textarea be known to be a "link"?  What will it link to?  (Side note, be very careful with cross-site-scripting and such.  A JavaScript command can be in a link.)

Why not use [a rich text editor](http://ckeditor.com/) which allows the user to create links?  Maybe something that supports [markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) like this site does?

Comment: I guess the best example would be on a message board when you highlight some text that you want as a link, then add in a url. I cant really use something like the rich text editor with the host I have to use.

Comment: @Guyver: What you're describing is precisely a rich text editor.  Why does your host not permit such a thing?  If you have to write your own (which is the path you're heading down), it'll be no different than using an existing one.  It'll just take longer to implement it.

Comment: @Guyver: I suppose you could code up your own fairly quickly based on a limited subset of markdown support.  Your users would just need to manually enter the markdown.  Unless you write the little paste-your-link-here pop-up div that would otherwise be used.

Comment: Maybe I could have them put something in like <li> to say hey this is a link? I work for a university, the server are locked down pretty tight.

Comment: @Guyver: I wouldn't recommend re-defining existing HTML tags for your own markup.  In the long run it won't make things simpler.  The servers are locked down so tight that you can't put code on them?  A third party rich text editor, especially for PHP, is just some PHP code files and some HTML and JavaScript.  If you can't use those, then coding this is going to be tricky...

Comment: @Guyver: In this particular case there's no difference.  It's just code being uploaded to the site and used in the PHP/JavaScript/HTML.  It's quite literally no different than coding one yourself, except that it's already done and more of an industry standard.